# How/Where do I give my github commit a version?

Tags: java, github, eclipse

I 'm just learning to give project versions.

I understand writing details about the changes in my project when committing, but where should I put my version number for my project?

Comment: You would tag a particular commit with a version. See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging

Comment: @MichaelT why not make it an answer so I can choose you?

Comment: I'll look into doing so (with a bit more than a link... unless someone else does so first).  However questions about how tools work is more appropriate for Stack Overflow than P.SE (see [how to use tags in GIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965080/) and [Git Tags & Branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318164/git-tags-branches)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on MichaelT's answer, you can just add a Git "tag" to mark a particular commit as a canonical version of your code.

Assuming your most-recent commit on the `master` branch is the commit you would like to tag:

`$ git tag 0.1.0`

...or whatever version you would like to set it to. In the future, if you, or someone else would like to work with that specific version of your code, all that would need to be done (after an initial `git-clone` of your repository) would be to run:

`$ git checkout tags/0.1.0`

If you are looking for a sensible scheme to follow for your projects' versions, I highly recommend [SemVer](http://semver.org/), as following a standard scheme for your projects' version makes it much easier to parse (if the need ever arises). SemVer also provides guidelines as to *how* to bump your version numbers.

Comment: Is the tag feature available in the Github GUI?

Comment: If you are referring to the web interface of GitHub, then no, it does not look like it is supported. If you are referring to the GitHub app for Mac, strangely enough, I do not see it in there either. However, if you are looking for a decent, graphical Git client, I highly recommend [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/).